# is_home() returns true while it shouldn't

Tags: conditional-tags

I have a problem with `is_home()`. It is placed in my `footer.php` and it returns `true` when it shouldn't. I have a page template on which I perform a query with `query_posts()`.

When I pass the following as the argument,

```
array( 'cat' => $lekarz_page_cat_id, 'paged' => get_query_var('paged') )
```

it returns `false` which is ok, but when the argument is

```
array('post__in' => $pz_posts, 'paged' => get_query_var('paged'))
```

it returns `true` when it shouldn't. Can someone tell me why this is so?

Comment: if you are using `query_posts()` in a template (not recommended, rather use `get_posts()` or `WP_Query()` ), you might need to end this with `wp_reset_query();` to reset the querystring to the original.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a static page for your homepage. Then you should be using `is_front_page();`. Check this link -> http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags

Comment: No I wasn't use static page as my homepage but now i'am and it works fine with `is_front_page();`. big THX